# Convert ETH to USDC using uniswap

Tags: solidity, ether, uniswap

I want to convert ETH to USDC using my solidity contract I am using the uniswapV2 contract for converting ETH to token I am using this function `swapExactETHForTokens` I am not able to get the path that will be used for swapping ETH to USDC.

This address of the WETH and UniswapV2 router is for goerli.

My Code:-

```
interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function swapExactETHForTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}


contract Test{
    address UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address WETH = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6;

    function ConvertEthToUSDC(address _tokenOut) public payable returns(bool) {
        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[1] = WETH;
        path[2] = _tokenOut;

        //Deadlimit 10 mins
        //minAmount is 0
        IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(0, path, msg.sender, block.timestamp + 600);        
    }
}
```

If I am not wrong there is some small thing I am missing using which I can get the conversion path.

Answer (score 1):

To get the conversion path for swapping ETH to USDC using the Uniswap V2 Router contract, you can use the `getPath` function.
Here is an example of how you can use the `getPath` function to get the conversion path and then use it in the `swapExactETHForTokens` function:

```
function ConvertEthToUSDC(address _tokenOut, uint _amountOut) public payable returns(bool) {
    // Get the conversion path
    address[] memory path = IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).getPath(_tokenOut, _amountOut);

    // Swap ETH for the desired tokens
    IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(0, path, msg.sender, block.timestamp + 600);
}
```